# What is the benefit of town twinning?

Tags: united-kingdom, local-government

So, here in the UK most towns have several 'twin towns' in other countries. These appear to be largely ceremonial, each town will have signs mentioning the other and there may occasionally be statues, benches etc. exchanged between the twins.

There's a running joke that councilors like to twin towns because they get to travel to potential twin towns and essentially have a free holiday courtesy of their position on the council.

Is there any significant benefit to the town itself, or the community who live there, to a town having twins?

Answer (score 1):

Usually there would be student exchanges and the like. Rather than going just anywhere abroad, school trips would go to the partner town where teachers and administrators know and trust their counterparts.

This may be less of an issue in this age of the internet, but before one could just google the details it mattered.

Comment: The *usually* here will heavily depend on the size of the two conurbations. It's by no means always the case that the numbers would match well enough for this.

Comment: @origimbo, I thought most twinnings were designed to make a good match. At least originally, which might have been half a century ago.

Comment: Something is almost always being matched, but it can be ideological, or linguistic as much as purely numerically demographic.